# ssrs display multiple documents

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have several RDL's that that are designed using textbox's to display data as a document to be converted to PDF or printed directly.  There is no table involved in the RDL's.  I am trying to get one of the RDL's to display multiple documents by passing a dataset of multiple DocumentId but it only appears to display the first document.  I figure there must be a setting to force a page break on the actual dataset or page itself but I have not found one yet.  Does anyone know of such a feature of SSRS 2008?

Comment: Sounds like a classic case for a **List** http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239330.aspx Set the the group to have page breaks between each instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the textbox in lists and have the list group on Documentid.  This should fix your issue.  If you want it to be shown on a separate page you should be able to select page break between groups.